# How do I parse a URL query string, and then inject the parsed variable(s) into the HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, string

I would like a solution to the two illustrated problems I outlined in the title. For example, how would I take a URL with a querystring, like:

`http://www.example.com/index.html?title=My%20Website`

Parse the querystring to get the value of the `title` attribute, and then inject that value into the HTML DOM, to use (for instance) as the page title? To reflect something like:

`<title>My Website</title>`

Comment: Question is not very clear... Can you give example of expected result and input data ?

Comment: I want to put in the html the name of the query string (in other words, i need some kind of script which, whenever a put a different query string, it will change the html content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the question, but what I'm assuming you want is an API by which the URL you enter into the browser governs some part of the DOM content. You can achieve this by using a querystring in your URL, having the javascript parse that URL for the query and then injecting the value of that parsed query into the HTML. So in pseudo code:

Enter the URL: `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html?title=My%20Webpage`

Parse that URL: `var result = myParseFunction(window.location.search)`

Inject the result into DOM: `document.querySelector("title").innerText = result`

I'm being super generic because I don't really understand the question, but from what you've said this would achieve what you want, I think. How you implement that is up to you.

Comment: yes, that's correct, i want to put query string values into html

Comment: what is myParseFunction?

Comment: It just represents whatever function you will use to parse your URL querystring. There are a number of implementations which provide solutions to parsing a URL querystring, right now I'm too busy to make one, so I posted the process to help you out as much as I can at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you want to decode search string is like `?q=here%20is%20my%20cool%20string`

You can access the URL parameters with

```
window.location.search
```

Then, you maybe want to get rid of the 'special' characters with decodeURIComponent, see specification here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

your parameters would finally look like this:

```
var myvar = window.location.search.decodeURIcomponent()
```